# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when trying to display metadata in nanoc

Tags: ruby, erb, nanoc

(Ruby noob)
I'm using nanoc to generate a site. Here is my sample page with metadata:

```
--- 
title: abc
parameters:
    abc: def
    ghi: ijk
---

test
```

I know that I can have parameters one level up but I want to access them in layout file:

```
<%= @item[:parameters][:abc] %>
```

but I got following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Parameters are passed to layout because when I do:

```
<%= YAML::dump(@item[:parameters]) %>
```

I can see them. As a Ruby noob I think there's a simple solution to my problem. Also, if you could post a snippet iterating through :parameters hash I would be grateful.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `YAML::dump` returns data while `@item[:parameters][something]` gives undefined method `[]` for `NilClass`. It's not possible. You can't be indexing `nil` with `[]` if `YAML::dump` shows there is something there. So are you sure that error is because of that particular code? Something else must be going on.

Comment: I agree with @Casper. I modified the tutorial adding your parameters and the layout change, it works just fine.

Comment: What does `<%= @item.class %>` and `<%= @item[:parameters].class %>` say?

Comment: When I do: <%= YAML::dump(@item[:parameters]) %> I got: -- 
:abc: def
:ghi: ijk
but <%= @item[:parameters][:abc] %> gives exception above. Maybe my Ruby is too old? ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: <%= @item[:parameters].class %> - Hash

Comment: <%= @item.class %> - Nanoc::Item

Comment: Ok..I think I know what's wrong. Do you have more than one page on your site?

Comment: @Casper, yes, three in a folder where a problem occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have more than one page on your site. Therefore `parameters` does not exist in the layout for every page nanoc processes. For some pages the element will be `nil` and hence the error you get.

Perhaps you need to rethink how you want to use those parameters, or then you need a conditional in your layout to look for `parameters` and only use them when they are present:

```
<% if @item[:parameters] %>
 <%= @item[:parameters][:abc] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly that's not the case. I got this error on page that has parameters in metadata.

Comment: @keepkimi And if you change the code to the above code, what happens?

Comment: @keepkimi I don't know how nanoc processes changes to pages, but the code without the `if` statement will fail the moment nanoc processes a page or layout file that did NOT load your page first that contains the `parameters` data. So you see even if nanoc says it only processes your one page, perhaps it has to do some comparisions internally and loads some pages that does not have `parameters` -> BOOM.